# Add a markup to an option of ListMultipleChoice Wicket 9

Tags: wicket

I want to add a "class" attribute to all the options of ListMultipleChoice but I can't find a way to achieve that.

Here's the markup that I get:

```
<select class="chooseChosenList chooseList" size="6" name="rolesChoicePanel:chosenList" id="idc8" multiple="multiple" title="Selected">
<option value="CONTRACT_ACCOUNT_MANAGER">Contract Account Manager</option>
<option value="CONTRACTS">Contracts</option>
<option value="REPORTER">Reporter</option>
<option value="IMPORTER">Data Importer</option>
<option value="DEVELOPER">Developer</option>
<option value="ADMIN">Administrator</option>
<option value="REGISTRATOR">Registration Operator</option>
<option value="UNRESTRICTED_CALLER">Unrestricted Caller</option>
<option value="SUPER_USER">Super User</option>
<option value="FINANCE">Finance</option>
<option value="TEAM_LEADER">Team Leader</option>
<option value="MANAGER">Manager</option>
<option value="MARKETING">Marketing</option>
</select>
```

And here's wicket code:

```
m_chosenList = new ListMultipleChoice<T>( "chosenList" );
    m_chosenList.setChoices( m_chosenListModel );
    m_chosenList.setDefaultModel( Model.ofList( new ArrayList<>() ) ); 
    m_chosenList.setOutputMarkupId( true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `#setOptionAttributes()` [method](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/acc979b3bae398bc695b7558f9cb49c73a818867/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractChoice.java#L525):

```
@Override
protected void setOptionAttributes(AppendingStringBuffer buffer, E choice, int index, String selected)
{
   super.setOptionAttributes(buffer, choice, index, selected);
   buffer.append(" class=\"MY_CLASS\" ");
}
```